# What is the name of the dual of vector fields?

Tags: terminology, differential-topology

It's all in the title : is there a standard name for the dual vector space of the space of vector fields (on a given manifold) ? I am not speaking about the dual bundle of the tangent bundle, which is of course the cotangent bundle.

I know for example that linear forms (continuous in a suitable topology) on differential forms are called currents. Is there a standard terminology for linear forms on vector fields ?

Answer (score 0):

In the de Rham picture, a vector (or multivector) is itself a current. The action of a vector $v$ on a 1-form $\omega$ is simply $\omega(v)$. Bivectors are functionals on 2-forms, et cetera.
In this picture, a vector field is "too much stuff"! 
As a distribution (or current), you can think of a vector as a highly singular $(n-1)$-form, just like a Dirac delta. 
A vector field would be something far from convergent, it would look like "an entire field" of Dirac delta's!

It would be too irregular for a current, so even more far from a test function/form.